# How to create "Customer Community User" under logged in user in the Community

Tags: apex, customer-community, userlicense

I have the community and logged in as a user with **Customer Community** user license and **Customer Community User** profile.
There is VF page with the table that shows Contacts related to the logged in User`s Account record.

Logged in user should have the possibility to create new community users that will be assigned to the same Account record.

I am trying to create the new user with `Site.createExternalUser(<user_instance>, <accoundId>)` method.

It throws an Exception `Site.ExternalUserCreateException: [You are already logged in.]`.

Is there any way on how to do that with **Site** class methods?
I assume, that otherwise I can create Contact and then in `@future` method (coz of mixed DML) create the User with ContactId.

Comment: That future method will still run in the context of the logged in User who triggered the future call, so I believe it will still throw the same exception. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009AiFIAU

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, how could I create the user then? Expose the REST service and make a "self" callout to create the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Platform Events, Platform Events run in the context of the Automated Process and thus they can be used for such scenarios.

1. Create an Event User_Creation_Event__e, with 2 fields, AccountID__C and UserJSON__C
2. Create a Trigger on User_Creation_Event__e which will create Community users,
3. From your COntroller , instead of calling `Site.ExternalUserCreateException`, just publish that event, by passing accountID and Serialized User JSOn .

Src: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics

Comment: Not sure if it is still the only way, but just came to say this seems like a pretty slick solution.